# Phantomjs with Selenium not processing iframe javascripts when try login to instagram

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe, phantomjs

I'm using python, with Selenium and PhantomJs
So I try to login to instagram but phantomjs is not processing iframes javascripts, when I try to do same thing with firefox all is ok.

```
my_iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe.hiFrame")
self.driver.switch_to.frame(my_iframe)
email = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='username']")))
```

it gives `timeout exception`.Am I doing something wrong?
Maybe there is any headless browser else I can use in selenium?

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have?

Comment: @ArtjomB.I tryed with 1.9.2,1.9.8,2.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use a implicit or explicit wait from selenium driver.
For example:

```
WebElement container = (new WebDriverWait(driver, maxTimeout))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id")));
```

that wait expect the element to exist and then get the element.
Iframe works good on Phantomjs 2.0

Sorry about my English

Comment: I will check and get back to you.